# how to pass encoded base64 data to HTTP worklight adapter

Tags: image, cordova, base64, ibm-mobilefirst, truncated

I have used cordova(navigator.camera.getPicture) to capture image from device. I converted the fileURI into base64 using file reader. But, when i assign the base64 url as img src whereas If i pass the same string to HTTP adapter(Worklight), I saw the encoded data truncated. Please help.

Thanks in advance.

Source Code:

```
    function tryToSend(evt) {
        encoding = evt.target.result;
        console.log("Encoded File: "+encoding);
        Ext.ComponentQuery.query('#encodedImage')[0].setHtml('<img style="height: 100px; width: 100px;" src="'+encoding+'" />');
        Ext.ComponentQuery.query('#encodedImage')[0].setHidden(false);
    }
    function win(file) {
        alert("FileName:"+file.name + ' & Type:' + file.type);
        selectedFileName = file.name;
        Ext.ComponentQuery.query('#originalImage')[0].setHtml('<img style="height: 100px; width: 100px;" src="'+file.fullPath+'" />');
        Ext.ComponentQuery.query('#originalImage')[0].setHidden(false);
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onloadend = tryToSend;
        var encoded = reader.readAsDataURL(file); 
    }
    function fail(error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
    function onResolveSuccessCompleted(fileEntry) {
        fileEntry.file(win, fail);
    }

    function onResolveFailed(error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
//Call on click of take pic button
function capPic(){
 navigator.camera.getPicture(onCapturePhoto, onFail, {
        quality: 50,
        destinationType: destinationType.FILE_URI,
        sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA,
        mediaType: navigator.camera.MediaType.ALLMEDIA,
    });
}
//Success
function onCapturePhoto(fileURI) {
    window.resolveLocalFileSystemURI(fileURI, onResolveSuccessCompleted, onResolveFailed);
    fileDetails.push({
        base64ImageData:encoding,
        fileName: selectedFileName,
    });
   alert("File Selected. Please Upload Now");
}

//Sending fileDetails array to HTTP adapter as parameter
var invocationData = {
            adapter : 'SAMPLE_ADAPTER',
            procedure : 'uploadFileNow',
            parameters : [fileDetails]
    };  
    WL.Client.invokeProcedure(invocationData, {
        onSuccess : fileUploadOK,
        onFailure : fileUploadFail,
    });
```

1) In Logcat, encoding in tryToSend Fn prints completely whereas the next line console.log gives truncated code

//Ajax call
`Ext.Ajax.request({
                    url: url,
                    method:'POST',
                    params:fileDetails,
                    success: function(response){
                        console.log(response);
                    },
                     failure:function(response){
                        console.log(response);
                     }
            });`

Comment: Why would you place the base64 string as the value for the img src? and why do you then mention adapter? and how about to provide some code or better explain your question?

Comment: I just want to check whether it is encoded properly,So assigned that encoded code to img src and it was good but If i pass the same to HTTP adapter,its get truncated

Comment: How do you convert it and send it? Add the code to your image. Is it a GET request?

Comment: Code added. Please check

Comment: This code does not show how you send it. Look at my question again please.

Comment: Have added complete code.. Kindly check and do the needful.

Comment: You did not get the adapter procedure implementation.

Comment: Could you please tell me what's the actual issue in my code, Objective is to get the complete string in Adapter to pass...

Comment: If you are doing a GET request, it may not be able to hold the entire value of the string.

Comment: If i directly hit AJAX request from client side, Am getting 404 thats the reason i am calling HTTP adapter..

adding AJAX POST call code

Comment: Aside of the truncated printing, is it Actually truncated? Is something actually failing for you other than the log printing?

Comment: Waiting to hear back from you.

Answer (score 1):

In my logcat the console.log can only print about 4k characters one time. So try to compare the encoded url's length to check if it's really be truncated.